# CSS, .htaccess, Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

My webpage has problems loading CSS documents, also with different typed of `link`ed documents, such as images. The CSS document is linked like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/master.css">`,

But my `.htaccess` is rewriting it into `index.php?query=master.css&search=Pages`

The error I get in the chrome console looks like this:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "/master.css". IconWiki:6

My `.htaccess` file

---

```
##############
# .htaccess  #
##############
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule "syspag/(.*)$" page.php?p=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule "sysico/(.*)$" icon.php?i=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule Icons/(.*)$ index.php?query=$1&search=Icons [QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?query=$1&search=Pages [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flag **T=text/css**

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?query=$1&search=Pages [QSA,T=text/css]
```

Comment: That is not the problem, the one you said to use T=text/css is incorrect, this is to navigate to for example /Home, /Search?q=blahblahblah, etc

Comment: Might work with setting it on example `RewriteRule CSS/(.*)$ css/$1.css [T=text/css]`

Comment: @Richard But that wouldn't work if you are referencing your CSS like `/master.css` (as you state in the question).

Comment: Correct, but then I can call it like `/CSS/master`